# How to overclock Intel i3 CPU using code. What parameter do I need to change for CPU overclocking? I don't want to use bios GUI

Tags: performance, cpu, clock, cpu-architecture

How to overclock Intel i3 CPU using code. What parameter do I need to change for CPU overclocking? I don't want to use bios GUI. I am using **Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3210 CPU @ 3.20GHz** CPU and Intel **DH61WW** Motherboard.